# Workaround for For Each Loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop, gmap.net

I need help, or maybe at least an idea to make things work..

I am working on routing the travel of *something* through gps..
first off, I pre-loaded latlng points on my .accdb (3 points)
I want them to be connected through a route..
here :

```
For Each dtrow In gpsDtable.Rows
        gpsMarker = New GMapMarker_Custom(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")), "vistaMarker")
        routes.Markers.Add(gpsMarker)
        'this code, adds all 3 points in the map as a marker..
        'yes it shows those 3. working good... then

        If routes.Markers.Count < 2 Then
           'this condition is, I think optional
           'I just used them because, routing needs to have 2 POINTS
           'so if there is no marker present, either side, exception
           'if there are 2, execute the code

        Else
           'this is the code to add the route between 2 points

            Dim rp As RoutingProvider = TryCast(mainMap.MapProvider, RoutingProvider)
            Dim route As MapRoute = rp.GetRouteBetweenPoints(gpsMarker.Position, gpsMarker.Position, False, False, CInt(mainMap.Zoom))
           'as you can see, I used gpsMarker as the first & last point
           'logically, I need it to be the same because
           'it will connect to itself since I use for each

            Dim r As New GMapRoute(route.Points, "")
            routes.Routes.Add(r)
        End If
    Next
```

In my theory..
tried to test this expecting to have : add marker, route, add second marker, route, add third marker and so on..
it came out to be, *I think*, it routes, but only routes to only one marker, the last one. so technically, you won't see a route. `I start here, I stop here` - something like that is happening.

I was thinking if you could help me have an idea, something like..

```
For each point in database  
add marker  
add second marker  
route  
add third  
route from second to third
and so on...
```

is there a way for VB to recognize the last marker? start from there and end on the new one..
or the marker that I want to be as the starting point and the end point. thanks SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rp.GetRouteBetweenPoints(gpsMarker.Position, gpsMarker.Position, False, False, CInt(mainMap.Zoom))
```

As far as I can tell you set a route from `gpsMarker` to itself.

If you want to route a travel that goes through each point in `gpsDtable.Rows` then you can just connect each marker with a previous one. Something like this:

```
'DISCLAIMER: untested code
Dim rp As RoutingProvider = TryCast(mainMap.MapProvider, RoutingProvider)
Dim previousGpsMarker As GMapMarker_Custom
For Each dtrow In gpsDtable.Rows
    gpsMarker = New GMapMarker_Custom(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")), "vistaMarker")
    routes.Markers.Add(gpsMarker)
    'If it's not a starting point
    If previousGpsMarker IsNot Nothing Then
        'Set a route from previous marker
        Dim route As MapRoute = rp.GetRouteBetweenPoints(previousGpsMarker.Position, gpsMarker .Position, False, False, CInt(mainMap.Zoom))            
        Dim r As New GMapRoute(route.Points, "")
        routes.Routes.Add(r)
    End If
    'Storing the previous marker
    previousGpsMarker = gpsMarker
Next
```

Comment: that condition will not work. I used boolean, and the old one on my question. still, either `previous` does not have a value, or they are the same with `gpsmarker` .. working on it ..

Comment: Why does this condition not work? Is `previousGpsMarker` always `Nothing`? What happens after the last assignment? P.S. `Count` condition from your question will skip the first marker.

Comment: that line is an error. maybe the API can't catch it. I used 2 so that it will have a start & end. because if its only a point, it would give out an exception. till now, I think its routing to itself. lol

Comment: `Is operator does not accept operands of type Integer. Operands must be reference or nullable types.`

Comment: @AdorableVB Please check out the updated code. It should be `IsNot`

Comment: what's the difference between the two? `is Not and isNot`?

Comment: It was just a typo. `IsNot` is a separate operator, the opposite of `Not`. `Is Not` is a combination of two different operators, `Not` should be used on booleans and doesn't work properly here.